# User can only enter O or E anything other than that will loop for correct input JAVA

Tags: java, string, loops, input

I am trying to code as user can only enter `'O'` or `'E'`, other than that should prompt try again and allow user to enter again until valid input but i have tried few ways but couldn't solve it.

```
System.out.println("Lets play a game called Odds and Evens");
System.out.print("What is your name? ");`
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = input.next();
System.out.print("Hi "+ name + ", Which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");
String select = input.next();
do {
    if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
        System.out.println(name + " is Odd! The computer will be Even!");
    } else if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
        System.out.println(name + " is Even! The computer will be Odd!");
    }
} while(!select.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || !select.equalsIgnoreCase("o"));
```

Comment: Either `while (!(select.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || select.equalsIgnoreCase("o")))` or `whlie(!select.equalsIgnoreCase("e") && !select.equalsIgnoreCase("o"))`, take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!select.equalsIgnoreCase("e") || !select.equalsIgnoreCase("o")` will always be true. The input cannot be simultaneously equal to both `"e"` and `"o"`, so it will be unequal to one of those. A good IDE will warn you about this by default. Also, the loop is not reprompting for input. Either way, it's going to spin forever.

How about something like this instead?

```
String select;
do {
    select = input.next();
    if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
        System.out.println(name + " is Odd! The computer will be Even!");
    } else if(select.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
        System.out.println(name + " is Even! The computer will be Odd!");
    }
} while(!select.equalsIgnoreCase("e") && !select.equalsIgnoreCase("o"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works, so the input was outside of the loop which is why not reprompting for input, thanks for you explanation. This will be the code after changes and some addings.